# Excel Vba, failed looping on column with innertext

Tags: excel, vba

It kept failing at looping the "details blue" classname , i want to get data like the image attached.

```
Do While (.Busy Or .readystate <> 4)
DoEvents
Loop

   For Each ele In .document.all

If ele.classname = "details_title" Then
  RowCount = RowCount + 1
  sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = ele.innertext


           ElseIf ele.classname = "details blue" Then
           i = 1
           For x = 0 To ele.Length  'error at this line
           i = i + 1
           sht.Cells(RowCount, i).Value = ele.Item(x).innertext 'error at this line
           Next x


 End If
 Next ele
```

=

Comment: have u tried ele.innertext

Comment: the page has multiple classname = details blue, i need to collect all innertext, if i use "ele.innertext" it will only get the last one

Comment: Did you try `For x = 0 To (ele.Length-1))`

Comment: Also try `Somevariable = Somevariable & vbnewline & ele.innertext`  inside the loop and then assign `Somevariable` to `sht.Cells(RowCount, i).Value` in the end?

Comment: Just tried(ele.Length-1), got run time error '438'
Object doesnt support this property or method.

Comment: I dont quit get your suggestion on Somevariable...sorry im newbie

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the elements one at a time into `ele` so (a) there won't be a `length` property because it's an element not a collection* and (b) you won't get all of the "details blue" elements at the same time

I suspect you probably want to use the `getElementsByClassName` method. You could replace the whole `For Each ele` to `Next ele` business with this:

```
Dim detailsTitles As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim detailsBlues As IHTMLElementCollection

Set detailsTitles = document.getElementsByClassName("details_title")

' There should only be one of these
If (detailsTitles.length = 1) Then
    RowCount = RowCount + 1
    sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = detailsTitles.item(0).innerText
Else
    ' do something - e.g. report an error to the user
End If

Set detailsBlues = document.getElementsByClassName("details blue")

i = 1
For Each ele in detailsBlues
    i = i + 1
    sht.Cells(RowCount, i).Value = ele.innerText
Next ele
```

If instead you actually have multiple "details_title" items which in turn have multiple associated "details blue" items then that would require a different approach (probably looking at the `parentElement` of the "details_title" item)

---

*some elements may have a property called `length` but that's not the same thing